# How to run a thread for one hour in java

Tags: java, multithreading

I will be receiving an attribute and I want to run a job for that attribute for 1 hour - monitoring and logging things related to that attribute. After that one hour, the job will stop.

Is there a way to run a task, thread or a job for one hour given a id for that thread? As far as I know, the SchedulerExecutorService runs with a delay and after a certain interval. But how can I stop the job for that particular thread after one hour.

One more thing to note here is - there is a thread which will run for one hour and terminate. And there is another thread inside the one hour thread which will be doing some work every 5 minutes. So all in all I want a job to run for one hour and then inside that thread, another thread which will run every 5 minutes.

Kindly help.

```
class Task1 implements Runnable {
    String abc;
    private final ScheduledExecutorService monitorService;
    private boolean isShutDown = false;

    public Task1(String abc) {
        this.abc = abc;
        this.monitorService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1, new ThreadFactoryBuilder().setNameFormat("checker-%s").build());
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.createStarted();
        monitorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Task2(abc), 2, 300000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        long elapsed = stopwatch.elapsed(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        if(elapsed == 3600000) {
            shutdownAndAwaitTermination(monitorService);
            isShutDown = monitorService.isShutdown() || monitorService.isTerminated();
        }
    }

    public boolean isShutDown()
    {
        return isShutDown;
    }
}



public class Task2 implements Runnable //This should run every 5 minutes
{
    private String abc;

    public Task2(abc) {
        this.abc = abc;
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        System.out.println(abc);
    }
}

Task1 task1 = new Task1("abc");
task1.run(); //This should run for 1 hour and terminate
```

Comment: check every 5 minutes if works 1 hour then stop task

Comment: But how do I cancel a thread?

Comment: Make the thread stop itself, rather than stopping it from outside `while (run = true){your method here}`? You could use a date/time value, or a boolean value to indicate if it should stop or not, and you can check the value each thread cycle, or the value can be updated from another thread if you need it to be dynamic.

Comment: So the thing here is - there is a thread which will run for one hour and terminate. And there is another thread inside the thread which will do the monitoring work every 5 minutes. So all in all I want a job to run for one hour and then inside that monitoring thread which will run every 5 minutes.

Comment: @PriyankaNaik your task need repeated execute or task is just cost long time?if the task repeated executed you can check task need to stop before excute.if task cost long time,need another thread to stop task。

Comment: Re, "there is another thread inside the thread." Banish that thought from your mind. There is no "inside" of a thread. You can write code that instructs one thread to _start_ another thread, and you can write code in which one thread is responsible for managing some other thread, but neither thread is "inside" the other. You should think of threads as _agents_ that execute your code.

Comment: Ok, So how do I terminate a runnable thread after a certain interval?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only proper way to terminate a thread is for a thread itself to exit the `run()` method. **Do not** stop, interrupt or kill the thread - read the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html#stop()) for explanation why.

Do something like this:

```
public void run() {
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    while (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime < 3600000) {
        // ... do your stuff here ...
    }
}
```

Comment: How can I know if the task is terminated? Because I have kept the task inside a concurrentHashMap to avoid creation of duplicate tasks.

Comment: @PriyankaNaik Set a boolean flag isTerminated = false in constructor and true as the last line of run(). Then you can query the flag from anywhere. Remember to synchronize access, or you can also use AtomicBoolean.